# Creating unique radio buttons for each item in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, radio-button

I am trying to make a questionnaire. I have an array and 5 responses for each question (item of the array). I want when a user answers all the questions in the array to be able to select a response whatever they like without overlapping. Here is what I currently have:

```
var sample_q = ["question1" , "question2" , "question3" , "question4", "question5", "question6" , "question7"]
var div = document.getElementById('questions');
for (var i in sample_q) {
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + sample_q[i];
    $('<br><input type="radio" name="opt1" value="positive" id="1">Yes</input>').appendTo('#questions');
    $('<br><input type="radio" name="opt2" value="negative" id="2">No</input>').appendTo('#questions');
    $('<br><input type="radio" name="opt3" value="not_applicable" id="3">NA</input>').appendTo('#questions');
    $('<br><input type="radio" name="opt4" value="something" id="4">Something</input>').appendTo('#questions');
    $('<br><input type="radio" name="opt5" value="nothing" id="5">Nothing</input><br>').appendTo('#questions');
}
```

The problems with this is that I can select multiple radio buttons for each question. Also, having 7 questions, and the scenario when I select different answer for every question, since I have 5 radio buttons, they are overlapping as the number of the questions is 7 and I have only 5 options for each. Also, all questions should be regarded as a whole and answered together.

Comment: if you want to group your radio buttons, so the user can select only one answer between multiple choices, you have to set the same `name` attribute value to all your grouped button. `<input type="radio" name="question1"  value="positive" id="1">` , `<input type="radio" name="question1"  value="negative" id="2">` . See: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: yes but the problem with that is when I iterate through a list of questions,
user can only answer at 1 question at a time which is not efficient

Comment: So, when a user click a radio button in the first question, you want to select the same answer for every other questions?

Comment: I wanted every question to have only one response.
That would be a unique response for each question, answered by the user.
Setting the i for name property solved my problem as it iterates and increases each time I've already set it to a radio button. Thanks though! (I am kinda newbie in stackoverflow and am sorry if the question was unclear misunderstood or by some people)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group your radio buttons, so the user can select only one answer between multiple choices, you have to set the same name attribute value to all your grouped button :

```
var sample_q = ["question1" , "question2" , "question3" , "question4", "question5", "question6" , "question7"]
var div = document.getElementById('questions');
for (var i in sample_q) {
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + sample_q[i];
    $('<br><input type="radio" name="' + i + '" value="positive" id="1">Yes</input>').appendTo('#questions');
    $('<br><input type="radio" name="' + i + '" value="negative" id="2">No</input>').appendTo('#questions');
    $('<br><input type="radio" name="' + i + '" value="not_applicable" id="3">NA</input>').appendTo('#questions');
    $('<br><input type="radio" name="' + i + '" value="something" id="4">Something</input>').appendTo('#questions');
    $('<br><input type="radio" name="' + i + '" value="nothing" id="5">Nothing</input><br>').appendTo('#questions');
}
```

See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/permnn6L/)

Comment: Yes, and setting 'i' as an unique identifier would work well as I iterate through all the questions and 'i' is once updated after the radio buttons are created and the name has been set. 

In other words, that would work as 5 radio buttons for each question would have same name but different from those for question 2. I see, Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your radio buttons the same name, that'll group them so that only one can be selected at any time. Good luck with your questionnaire.